# How do I advance slides in a Google Docs presentation for viewers?

Tags: google-slides

Currently, I have to use a desktop sharing utility (like [Adobe ConnectNow](http://www.productivity501.com/adobe-connectnow/3184/)) to share my application window that contains my slides. I'm thinking it would be easier to share my slides on Google Docs, but I don't know how to advance the slides for my viewers. When I switch slides locally, my viewers continue to see the 1st slide instead of the slide I'd like to show. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

(*I prefer not to use timed slides that automatically advance.*)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not a Google Docs feature (and not possible) based on online documentation and no better answer. Apparently, this [worked](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/importing--exporting/aOJ2wC3cvQ8) at one point in Google Docs, but it required viewers to use Google Talk (and this combination was buggy at the time).

An alternative I went with is PowerPoint 2010, which comes with a feature to [broadcast slideshows to users over the Internet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/share-presentations-painlessly-with-broadcast-slide-show-HA101792302.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Hangouts video chat and share your screen. For further details see [Share your screen during a Hangout - Google Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/1660627?hl=en)